# How to search lists into a nested list by their second key and append it to another list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, nested-lists

Here is given a nested list:

```
nl=[['Tina', 37.2], ['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Harsh', 39], ['Akriti', 41]]
```

Now I have to search for the lists which second value is 37.21. Those lists which second value get matched with 37.21, will be appended into another list.

So the output should be:

```
['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21]
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You iterate over the whole list `nl` and extract the value at the second index of the nested lists and compare it with the desired value , if it matches then you simply append the nested list to another list `answer`

```
nl=[['Tina', 37.2], ['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Harsh', 39], ['Akriti', 41]]        

answer = []

for sample_list in nl:
    if sample_list[1]==37.21:
        answer.append(sample_list)
print answer
>>> [['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21]]
```

Comment: @AbdullahAlImran an Upvote in return would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```
 [l for l in nl if l[1] == 37.21]
```

which returns

```
[['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21]]
```